# What mime-type should I return for a python string

Tags: python, http, mime-types

I have a web API that returns python dictionaries or lists as a response that I eval() in python scripts that use the API, for completness I wanted to set a proper content-type but not sure what would be best to use "text/x-python" or maybe "application/python", or something else?

[edit] I'm also outputting JSON, I'm doing Python as an option mainly for internal use.[/edit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authoritative registry is [at IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/) and, no, there is no standard subtype for Python. So, do not use type like "application/python" but you may use private subtypes such as "text/x-python" (the one I find in the mime-support package on my Debian).

Comment: The mime-support package source can be downloaded from: http://packages.debian.org/sid/mime-support. There is a file named mime.types that contains the mappings.

Comment: The use of “x-” is not valid anymore, it should be “x.” and “x.” is discouraged anyway.

Answer (score 8):

I doubt there's an established MIME type.  Have you considered using JSON instead, it is almost the same as a Python dict, and has a better established culture of tools and techniques.

Comment: I agree that JSON might well be best.  Plus call eval() on some arbitrary string retrieved from a web service seems a little insecure...

Comment: I'm outputting both as an option, I settled on "application/json" for that one. 

Internally we use alot of python so I wanted to provide something that had required no external modules to use.

Comment: The json module is included in 2.6. Besides, for the most part you can eval json and get sensible results (though as John mentions, that's not necessarily a great idea).

Comment: Seconded, eval() is a really really bad idea.